# Need a title for my tabel without making it to a link

Tags: html

I'm trying to give a table a title but it doesn't include it in the table/the title doesn't have a color around itself. I know that the mistake is this line `<li><a>Left</a></li>` but I don't know how to include it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

a:link, a:visited {
display: block;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #98bf21;
width: 120px;
text-align: center;
padding: 4px;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:hover, a:active {
background-color: #7A991A;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
<li><a>Left</a></li>
<li><a href="#info">Info</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
<li><a href="#">Left</a></li>
```

Comment: I know, but that doesn't make it to a title.

Comment: Is there a certain css or html element are you wanting to use to distinguish it as the title, like h1, h2, or ?  The term "title" is an html element, but I don't think that's the one you want:  [HTML element "Title"](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_title.asp).  Maybe you just should make it bold or underlined to show that it's a header?  You can do that by adding a class and some css:   `<li class="bold"><a href="#">Left</a></li>` and then in the css `.bold{font-weight:bold;}`

Comment: Here's a fiddle example:  http://jsfiddle.net/gratiafide/30b1f3zy/ since you already did make all the links bold, you can just make the "title" or "header" a larger font size, or add an underline, or maybe change its colors (which would require more work though).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what you have created is not a `table` but an `unordered list`.

That being said, the reason your `<a>` tag is not being styled is the lack of a `href="#"` attribute.

And with *that* said, you should **not** be using a `<li><a>text</a></li>` structure for showing the title of what looks like a navigation bar. Especially when the only reason to use an anchor tag is because of your existing CSS.

Instead, take the `<li><a href="#">Left</a></li>` line, put it before the `<ul>` tag and just turn it into a `div`.

Then use some additional CSS to target and style that `<div class="title">`.

Comment: Can a div have more than one attribute like; color, background-color etc.? Have tried to give title more than just one but it doesn't work.

Comment: @user4118143 Of course. Use an appropriate selector in CSS (ex. ``.title``) and then just put all of the different styles in the curly braces just like you would with any kind of selector. See this http://jsfiddle.net/mklopets/v9ug6782/